# Change the on-screen position of the Turtle Graphics window?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is it possible to change the position of the turtle console on screen?

My main objective is to write code that can move the window, that's all.

I'm using Python 3.4.0 under Windows 10.

If any extra information is needed please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do folks *always* jump into `tkinter` before reading the turtle documentation?

Yes, you can set the screen position of the turtle graphics window using the same `setup()` method you use to size it:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def animate():
    global offset

    screen.setup(width=0.333, height=0.333, startx=offset, starty=offset)

    turtle.dot(offset)

    offset += 10

    if offset < 300:
        screen.ontimer(animate, 100)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()

offset = 30

animate()

screen.exitonclick()
```

`startx`, if positive, is the starting position in pixels from the left edge of the screen, or from the right edge if negative.  Similarly, `starty`, if positive, is the starting position from the top edge of the screen, or from the bottom edge if negative.  By default, the window is centered on the screen.

Your title asks about the position of the ***Turtle Graphics*** window on the screen but the body of your question asks about the ***Turtle Console***.  These might be considered two different windows.

> My main objective is to write code that can move the window

I can't tell if you just want to set the initial position of the window or actually move the window around the screen so I rewrote my example to demonstrate the later.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify this I just wan the Turtle Graphics window to open in a position and stay still afterwards.

Comment: @Pleasedon'tjudgeme. `screen.setup(width=0.333, height=0.333, startx=offset, starty=offset)`  thil line works

Comment: I like your program the way it moves!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to get the root window that contains the Tkinter Canvas that the turtle is using as its [TurtleScreen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.TurtleScreen). Once you have that window you can change its [geometry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method).

Here's a simple demo.

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(width=0.5, height=0.5)
screen = turtle.Screen()

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()
canvas = screen.getcanvas()

left, top = 30, 100
geom = '{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, left, top)
canvas.master.geometry(geom)

t = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Since you're calling `turtle.setup()` anyway, why not simply specify its optional `startx` and `starty` arguments and avoid the extra code?

Comment: @cdlane The OP said they want to _change_ the window's position. They didn't say anything about setting its initial placement.

Comment: True, but my question stil stands.  ;-)  The `setup()` methods appears up to the task, on my OS X system, I don't know what happens on Windows.

Comment: @cdlane Ah, ok. I must confess I've never tried to modify the Turtle screen via `.setup`. And I don't use Windows either, so I have no idea how it behaves there.