# Turtle. Set the initial app window position

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to set the starting window for my first turtle script, but after some searching it seems that there is no clean way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the on-screen position of the Turtle Graphics window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081195/change-the-on-screen-position-of-the-turtle-graphics-window)

Answer (score 0):

> after some searching it seems that there is no clean way to do it

What do you mean by ***clean***?  You can set the initial size and starting position of the turtle window using the `setup()` method:

```
>>> import turtle
>>> help(turtle.setup)
Help on function setup in module turtle:

setup(width=0.5, height=0.75, startx=None, starty=None)
    Set the size and position of the main window.

    Arguments:
    width: as integer a size in pixels, as float a fraction of the 
      Default is 50% of 
    height: as integer the height in pixels, as float a fraction of the
       Default is 75% of 
    startx: if positive, starting position in pixels from the left
      edge of the screen, if negative from the right edge
      Default, startx=None is to center window horizontally.
    starty: if positive, starting position in pixels from the top
      edge of the screen, if negative from the bottom edge
      Default, starty=None is to center window vertically.
```

For example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(300, 300, startx=100, starty=200)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.dot(100)

screen.mainloop()
```