# How to specify where Turtle Screen window opens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

How can I tell a Turtle window where to open, based on screen dimensions and Turtle window size? I would like it to open in the middle.

I will appreciate all the answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the on-screen position of the Turtle Graphics window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081195/change-the-on-screen-position-of-the-turtle-graphics-window)

Comment: Did you [look at the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setup) or [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081195/change-the-on-screen-position-of-the-turtle-graphics-window) [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142976/turtle-set-the-app-window-position-on-my-computer) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202684/turtle-set-the-initial-app-window-position)? Docs from the first link seem to indicate that it opens in the middle by default. Is that not your experience?