# Turtle. Set the app window position on my computer

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there a way to change the default position of starting window for turtle scripts running on my computer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the on-screen position of the Turtle Graphics window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081195/change-the-on-screen-position-of-the-turtle-graphics-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the default position of starting window for
> turtle scripts running on my computer? ... I did not mean in the
> program. But someway to change the default of startx, so it opens the
> window with the new default unless changed in python script.

Yes.  You can set the `leftright` and `topbottom` properties in a **turtle.cfg** configuration file (in your home directory.)  These act just like the `startx` and `starty` arguments to `setup()`, but are the default as long as you have them set in your **turtle.cfg** file:

- `startx`: if positive, starting position in pixels from the left
  edge of the screen, if negative from the right edge
  Default, `startx=None` is to center window horizontally.
- `starty`: if positive, starting position in pixels from the top
  edge of the screen, if negative from the bottom edge
  Default, `starty=None` is to center window vertically.

The corresponding **turtle.cfg** file would contain:

```
leftright = 100
topbottom = 100
```

to make the turtle window always open 100 pixels from the left and top of the screen unless set otherwise in the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a screen defined in some way similar to `screen = Screen()`. If you do, it should be easy to set the starting position of the window. Use the `screen.setup()` method as follows:

```
screen.setup(startx=someNumHere, starty=someNumHere)
```

where `startx` is the starting position in pixels from the left edge of the screen, and `starty` is the starting position in pixels from the top edge of the screen. So, for example, add this to your script:

```
screen.setup(startx=300, starty=300)
```

if you want the window to be 300px from the left and 300px from the top of the screen.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48083695/15603884) if you need further detail on the subject.

Comment: Actually I did not mean in the program. But someway to change the default of startx, so it opens the window with the new default unless changed in python script.